# Is there a way to specify an SPN when using LinqPad to connect to MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, kerberos, linqpad

We are working with SQL Server using Windows authentication and have found that we need to specify the SPN for the connection to work.  Our application is partially using VB6 connecting via UDL files and partially a series of ad hoc scripts that we run through LinqPad. 
Using the Server SPN feature of the UDL file we can get the connection to work but can not find the equivalent for LinqPad.

Does anyone know how to get this working?  We have tried ServerSPN= as an additional connection string parameter on the Advanced settings but it is unrecognised.

Further details.

- The client applications are on Windows 7 in domain A.  All of the client connections are made from accounts in domain A.
- The sql server is in domain B.
- There is a selective one way trust between the domains and the server is added to the group that enables that trust.
- The error from the linqpad connection is: "The target principal name is incorrect.Cannot generate SSPI context".
- The UDL file allows the connection to work once it has the Server SPN = value set but otherwise gets the same error.

Update:
During testing we have found that specifying the SPN results in NTLM authentication to the server.  Therefore if there is a way to force this from the client that would be a possible route for us.

Update + Workaround:  We have stumbled across a workaround, adding the server into the hostfile with a different name seems to trigger the same fall back to NTLM authentication to work for the LinqPad connection.  Would still appreciate if anyone understands how to fix this correctly but for now we are using the hostfile workaround.

Any help appreciated

Comment: SPN for SQL Server is normally required only if you need Kerberos delegation to work, otherwise Windows auth works perfectly fine without it. What exactly is the problem with LinqPad connections, can you provide more details?

Comment: I am not entirely clear on the underlying reason but I believe it is because we use selective trusts and the authentication is cross domain.   Specifying the SPN allows the connection to work (in the UDL file) but I can not find a way of specifying the SPN in linqpad - the error from linqpad is Cannot Generate SSPI Context.

Comment: Please update your question with as many details as possible. Kerberos is a complicated topic.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of several possible issues here:

- Your one-way trust is set up the wrong way around;
- It's too selective;
- Incompatibility in AD versions between domains.

I would recommend trying [Kerberos Configuration Manager for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39046), it might give you some insight into the root cause.

Also, I believe you might have better chances asking this on ServerFault rather than here. By the looks of it, it's a misconfiguration issue, and has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Hi thanks - that's a good point about server fault, I had hoped someone using LinqPad might know how to change the setting but you are right its probably something to do with the underlying configuration.  We have tried the kerberos configuration manager and found that servers without SPNs work as they fall back to NTLM.   Thanks for taking the time.